# How to read other user's PATH environment variable in Java

Tags: java

In most UNIX systems, you can retrieve other users' PATH environment variables by using "`su - [username] -c 'echo $PATH'`".

Is it possible to do this in Java?

I am aware `System.getenv("PATH")` can only give the system environment information not individual users. Is there a simple way to get this information rather than using `ProcessBuilder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to do by using `ProcessBuilder`, etcetera.  Java generally does not support things that cannot be done (relatively) portably.

The actual task being performed here requires privilege escalation.  The "su" command requires "root" privilege to change to the identity of the other user.  Any other way of doing this would *also* require "root" privilege ... because what you are doing is reading a file owned by a different user.  Running a Java application as "root" is kind of dangerous<sup>1</sup>.

In short: if you wanted to run "su -  -c echo $PATH" via ProcessBuilder, then the JVM would need to be running with "root" privilege.  Dangerous!

Beware: make sure that your mechanism for finding out the PATH of another doesn't turn into a massive security hole.

One way to address this is to write some secure apps (not in Java!) to do some very specific security sensitive tasks.  Audit them.  Then use `chown` and `chmod` to make them "setuid root".  Restrict execute rights to a specific group, and run your Java application in that group.

But a better idea is to avoid having to do this kind of thing from Java in the first place.

---

<sup>1 - The actual risk depends on all sorts of things.  Is the Java application exposed outside of the machine?  Can you restrict access to the machine?  Is there sensitive information or services on the machine?  Are running the latest version / release of Java at all times?  Can you trust all of the frameworks, libraries, etc that your Java application uses?  Have they been audited?</sup>